# How to make an ASP Web Application Forms suitable for Different Mobile Devices?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, mobile-application, device

We Have Plan to make Mobile Application Which is suitable for All Type of Standard Mobiles. So we choose the ASP Application, Because it Works in Browser, No Installation Files in Mobile Devices and It Connect to the WiFi with MySQL Server.

I want to Resize the ASP Web Application Forms height and Width suitable for Different Mobile Devices ?

One friend suggested to include jquery mobile and css in the ASP.net? Please Give your Valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way here is to detect whether the browser is a mobile device or not and then select a new style sheet accordingly.

It can get quite involving detecting all of the different devices out there and their capabilities and so initially I would suggest that you only cater for a few screen sizes.

You could place something like this code in the default.aspx

```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Redirect mobile users to the mobile site
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (!httpRequest.Browser.IsMobileDevice) 
        {
            string path = httpRequest.Url.PathAndQuery;
            bool isOnMobilePage = path.StartsWith("/Mobile/",
                                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (!isOnMobilePage)
            {
                string redirectTo = "~/Mobile/";

                // Could also add special logic to redirect from certain 
                // recognised pages to the mobile equivalents of those 
                // pages (where they exist). For example,
                // if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is UserRegistration)
                //     redirectTo = "~/Mobile/Register.aspx";

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here I've duplicated the web pages in a sub directory /mobile as I was implementing mobile support on a current web application. Duplicated code I know but it was the quickest way of doing it.

In my `mobile.master` page I have the following:

> ```
> <link href="../Css/Mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" type="text/css" />
> <link href="../Css/Mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="Screen" type="text/css" title="default"/>
> <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/thin.css" title="thin"/>
> <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/wide.css" title="wide"/>
> <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/medium.css" title="medium"/>
> ```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Javascript/resolution.js'></script>
```

The script itself (resolution.js) is:

```
function getBrowserWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        return window.innerWidth;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }
    else if (document.body) { return document.body.clientWidth; }
    return 0;
}


function dynamicLayout() {
    var browserWidth = getBrowserWidth();

    //Load Thin CSS Rules
    if (browserWidth < 640) {
        changeLayout("thin");
    }
    //Load Wide CSS Rules
    if ((browserWidth >= 640) && (browserWidth <= 900)) {
        changeLayout("medium");
    }
    //Load Wider CSS Rules
    if (browserWidth > 900) {
        changeLayout("wide");
    }
}

function changeLayout(description) {
    var i, a;
    for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
        if (a.getAttribute("title") == description) { a.disabled = false; }
        else if (a.getAttribute("title") != "default") { a.disabled = true; }
    }
}

function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() { obj["e" + type + fn](window.event); }
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
    }
}

addEvent(window, 'load', dynamicLayout);
addEvent(window, 'resize', dynamicLayout);
```

I then have 3 style sheets, thin, medium and wide that get called. It would be worth placing a link back to the full size web page for those with smart phones that can handle a standard browser sized web page.

The style sheets not only dictate screen size, but font, colours and item locations.

Tables are a real pain here as they don't resize well. I replaced mine with divs and floating blocks whose positions are dictated by the style sheet.

I hope that this helps to get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Search for mobile friendly HTML/CSS layouts, start having a look at http://www.getskeleton.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AMF: ASP.NET Mobile Framework](http://amf.codeplex.com/)
Especially siutable for iPhone/iPad platform, but can be a little bit slaggish on Android. 
Use only ASP.NET infrastructure, but don't allow to use ViewState and standard ASp.NET controls as well. But for mobile development it's a more convinient restriction.